# drupal 7 profile 2 how to create field profile url as NAME

Tags: users

Why is it so hard to create a view so others can see it? I just read the instructions at dupal.org documentation and checked out ep#33 of daily dose but neither are helping.

My view is set up with a grid of fields filtered by type main profile. I can't get the names as link to profile; all I can get is profile:url which looks ridiculous.

How can I get my profile:url field to be the link for a name?

[url] == Profile: URL   <--- how is this inputed for replacement field?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out finally.

You need to add fields in correct order to then use replacement which is [url]

for link to profile name.